# Convert efficiently the long table from Excel to LATEX?

Tags: tables, longtable, excel2latex, exceltex

- I have a long table in MS Excel.
- **How to convert the (long) table from Excel to LaTeX?**
- Yes, I have read some methods to achieve this on this site. But my table is very long.
- I can' t transform efficiently my table by using the methods.
- Could you help me?

*(Screenshot by user Dr. Manuel Kuehner - I also have deleted the download link because it is potentially dangerous and not long-term stable.)*
[image]

Comment: Have a look here http://johncanning.net/wp/?p=1019

Comment: As suggested @BlackMild, but then put some effort (for manual tweak) in obtained code to make it more clear, concise and adopted to `longtable` table.

Comment: As always such helping tools can do only a basic job, the created code always needs an reworking. For example excel2latex is known to use too mutch `\multicolumn` commands ... Sometimes it is better to create the table by your own ... Can you add an screenshot of your table to your question?

Comment: -1 for no effort and voted to close. And, consider accepting answers to your previous questions by click the tick mark below the vote button.

Answer (score 1):

- This is an alternative and fast approach (to the comments so far).
- Your table is very long and you seem to be new to LaTeX.
- I would convert the Excel table in a PDF (picture) and then would include it with `pdfpages` or `includegraphics`.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% \captionof
\usepackage{caption}

% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Test Header Right}
\lhead{Test Header Left}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\section{Test Section}
Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. 

\subsection{Test SubSection}
Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. 

\includepdf[
    pages = 1,
    pagecommand = {
        \pagestyle{fancy} 
        \captionof{table}{Experiment results.}
        },
    %fitpaper = true, % see manual for more information
    %noautoscale = true, % see manual for more information
    ]{Table_PDF.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

*(Screenshot of the PDF version of the Excel table)*
[image]

Comment: Looking this, almost unreadable code, I wonder what OP like to tell to readers with it?

Comment: @Zarko My thoughts exactly, maybe it's for the appendix.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Even contents in the appendix should be readable. Don't you think?

Comment: May be OP is going to print this in a much bigger paper ;)